# Why aren't identical xlrd xldates the same?

Tags: python, xlrd

In xlrd, why aren't identical-looking xldates considered the "same"

```
dates[0:10]
Out[92]: 
[xldate:41415.0,
 xldate:41422.0,
 xldate:41422.0,
 xldate:41422.0,
 xldate:41422.0,
 xldate:41422.0,
 xldate:41422.0,
 xldate:41422.0,
 xldate:41422.0,
 xldate:41422.0]

cmp(dates[1],dates[2])
Out[95]: -1
```

I also tried using creating a list(set(list)) to single out the unique dates with no luck:

```
len(dates)
Out[96]: 1636

len(list(set(dates)))
Out[97]: 1636
```

Why aren't these the same?

Comment: How is `dates` defined?

Comment: Sorry, I should have included that.  Yes, type(dates[0])
Out[116]: xlrd.sheet.Cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are, you are working with `Cell` objects.  These objects are not comparable.  You will want to compare the `value` that the cells are holding, not the cells themselves.

```
# i.e., 
cmp(dates[1].value, dates[2].value)
```